# PHP - MySQL : how to get item_id in the same page when i select the item_name in option dropdown

Tags: php, mysql

I need to show the `item_id` when I click one of the `item_name` list in the dropdown. And when I click submit, the `item_name` and `item_id` got by `$_POST`. Can javascript use to do that?

```
<?php
    $brg="SELECT item_id, item_name FROM tblItem";
    $b=mysql_query($brg);
?>
<td align="center">
    <select name="item_name">
        <?php while($br=mysql_fetch_array($b)){ ?>
        <option value=<?echo $br[0].'_'.$br[1]?> selected>
            <?php echo $br[1]; ?>
        </option>
        <?php } ?>        
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

Jup, that's possible with Javascript.

Your HTML:

```
<select name="item_name">
    <option value="1_Cheese">Cheese</option>
    <option value="2_Cars">Cars</option>
    <option value="3_Planes">Planes</option>
</select>

<input type="button" onclick="alert(getSelectedValue())" value="Get Select Id" />​
```

And your Javascript, to access the ID from the options value:

```
function getSelectedValue()
{
    var sel = document.getElementsByName('item_name')[0];
    return sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value.split("_")[0];
}
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acz6Q/

It would be a little easier with jQuery (also appended an event handler):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("select[name=item_name]").on("change", function()
    {
         alert("new item id = " + $(this).val().split("_")[0]);
    });    ​
});
```

And here is the jQuery version fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acz6Q/1/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to get the option choice from mysql?

Comment: What do you mean with "option choice"? You only have access to the html at that point, if you had in mind to query the database again at this point in time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="item_id" name="item_id" />
    <input type="hidden" id="item_name" name="item_name" />
    <select id="my_select" name="my_select">
        <option value="item_id_1">item_name_1</option>
        <option value="item_id_2">item_name_2</option>
        <option value="item_id_3">item_name_3</option>
    </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#my_select").change(function() {
            $("#item_id").val($("#my_select").val());
            $("#item_name").val($("#my_select option:selected").text());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Note that you need to include the jQuery library first. Also you can see how it works from here [jsfiddle.net/2FsNP/3](http://jsfiddle.net/2FsNP/3). And with this method you don't need to combine between value and text of the option tag with the underscore.

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to change <option value="item_id_1">item_name_1</option>
        <option value="item_id_2">item_name_2</option>
        <option value="item_id_3">item_name_3</option> with option i get from mysql? if yes, then what should i do? Thank you

Comment: inside your while loop put this line:                              echo "<option value='{$br['item_id']}'>{$br['item_name']}</option>";